# Заполнение DataGridView из двух потоков

Tags: c#, winforms, многопоточность, datagridview

Возникла необходимость заполнить один столбец `DataGridView` несколькими потоками, причём задержка в каждом потоке разная. Если один поток уже заполнил ячейку то второй её пропускает и в ячейке отображается значение только из одного потока а если они одновременно заполняют ячейку тогда оба значения отображаются. Возможно ли в принципе это реализовать и если можно, то подскажите как. Таким образом я хочу смоделировать столкновение информационных кадров в локальной сети(лабораторная работа). У меня получается так что в ячейка заполняется из обоих потоков одновременно. Буду рад любой помощи, совету или критике.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    Random m_random = new Random((int)DateTime.Now.Ticks);
    ManualResetEvent m_stopThreadsEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView1.RowCount = 10;
    }

    private void ThreadOne()
    {
        int n = m_random.Next(1000);
        AppendText("1");
    }

    private void ThreadTwo()
    {
        int n = m_random.Next(1000);
        AppendText("1");
    }

    delegate void AppendTextDelegate(string text);

    private void AppendText(string text)
    {
        if (dataGridView1.InvokeRequired)
        {
            dataGridView1.Invoke(new AppendTextDelegate(this.AppendText), new object[] { text });
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value +=text;
            }
        }
    }

    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        m_stopThreadsEvent.Set();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView1.RowCount = 10;

        Thread t1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ThreadOne));
        Thread t2 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ThreadTwo));

        t1.Start();
        Thread.Sleep(300);
        t2.Start();
        Thread.Sleep(600);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я привык работать с привязками данных, поэтому у меня в примере будут привязки. Я буду использовать `BindingList<T>` и реализацию `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

На форме есть самая обычная `Button` и самая обычная `DataGridView` с автогенерацией колонок.

Создам класс, который будет представлять собой строчку таблицы. И обеспечу потокобезопасность при доступе к его свойству, а так же сделаю вызов события `PropertyChanged` в UI потоке. Чтобы на 100% быть уверенным, что "чудеса" происходят не по вине рассинхрона при обращении к данным из нескольких потоков.

```cs
public class Data : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private object _syncRoot = new object();
    private string _value = "";
    private Form _form;

    // если включена автогенерация колонок, заголовок колонки берется отсюда
    [DisplayName("Abonent1")]
    public string Value
    {
        get
        {
            lock (_syncRoot)
            {
                return _value;
            }
        }

        set
        {
            lock (_syncRoot)
            {
                _value = value;
            }
            _form.Invoke((Action)(() => OnPropertyChanged()));
        }
    }

    public Data(Form form)
    {
        _form = form;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

И реализую сам пример

```cs
public partial class Form1 : Form, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private const int _count = 10;

    private BindingList<Data> _items;

    public BindingList<Data> Items
    {
        get => _items;
        set
        {
            _items = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        dataGridView1.DataBindings.Add("DataSource", this, nameof(Items));
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Items = new BindingList<Data>();
        for (int i = 0; i < _count; i++)
        {
            Items.Add(new Data(this));
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < _count; i++)
            Items[i].Value = "";
        Thread t1 = new Thread(ThreadOne);
        Thread t2 = new Thread(ThreadTwo);
        t1.Start();
        t2.Start();
    }

    private void ThreadOne()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < _count; i++)
            AppendText(i, "1");
    }

    private void ThreadTwo()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < _count; i++)
            AppendText(i, "2");
    }

    private void AppendText(int position, string text)
    {
        string s = Items[position].Value;
        Thread.Sleep(1); // <--- вот здесь происходит столкновение потоков
        // к моменту выполнения следующей строчки, переменная 's' и 'Items[position].Value'
        // могут иметь разное значение
        if (s == "")
            Items[position].Value += text;
        Thread.Sleep(10);
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

Ну и при нажатии на кнопку получаю следующий вывод в `DataGridView`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не понятно только зачем форме реализовывать INPC, если `Items = new BindingList<Data>();` делается только один раз в конструкторе формы?

Comment: @Bulson еще раз взгляните на конструктор.

Comment: Хорошо, не в конструкторе, а обработчике события загрузки формы, что почти одно и тоже в данном случае.

Comment: @Bulson если я уберу INPC не перемещая код в конструктор, работать перестанет. Так что у меня просто вот так вот сделано. Ничего лишнего. :) Не вижу ничего позорного в использовании `DataBindings`. Можно конечно просто присвоить `DataSource`, можно сделать как все делают - убрать класс данных и насиловать ячейки напрямую. Кому как нравится.

Comment: благодарю за ответ. я не знал раньше об этом способе